# Eclipse RCP performance

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-leaks, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse 3.x rcp application which enables users to open multiple views having a `GridTableViewer` Widget with potentially few hundreds to thousands of rows each. The input is an `ArrayList`.I noticed a problem. When I close a view the heap memory doesn’t seem to reduce. I am looking at windows task manager.this is causing java memory overflow errors after opening 3 or more views with few thousand rows each. I am following swt widget disposal strategies. My suspicion is that the array input of each of these views is not freed up when I close a view.is GC not properly working ?

Comment: Note that a view is not necessarily closed (i.e. disposed of) when you click the little cross. If it is opened in one or more other perspective(s), it will stay open until it is closed in the last perspective showing it.

Comment: I can see that the view’s dispose method is called. So the dispose is happening.

Comment: Any other suggestions to effective memory management?